# How to force line breaks when display:flex is applied on text?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox

```css
.row {
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: start;
}

.gap {
  row-gap: 12px;
  column-gap: 12px;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="col fullwidth">
  <div class="row fullwidth gap">
    <label style="width:100px;">
        <template slot="text">
          <div>Very long text very long text</div>
        </template>
      </label>
    <label class="grow">
        <template slot="text">
          <div>text text</div>
        </template>
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="row fullwidth gap">
    <inputText style="width: 100px;" />
    <inputText class="grow" />
  </div>
  <div class="row fullwidth gap">
    <label style="width: 100px;">
        <template slot="default">
          <div>Please type in the name of your city</div>
        </template>
      </label>
    <label class="grow">
        <template slot="default">
          <div>Please type in the name of your city</div>
        </template>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display two input fields side by side and above and below some labels and descriptions. The labels and inputs are both vue components and display:flex is applied to the label component.
Now, what I want to accomplish is, that the overflow of the label gets broken up into the next line. The div, that wraps around the first label and the input has a fixed width of 100 px. Nonetheless, the content still overflows.
I have tried flex-wrap but it will not work. It is necessary for the label to maintain display:flex.
[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4JPJ.png)

What's basically applied on the label:

```
.label {
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}
```

My example:

```
<div class="col fullwidth">
    <div class="row fullwidth gap">
      <label style="width:100px;">
        <template slot="text">
          <div>Very long text very long text</div>
        </template>
      </label>
      <label class="grow">
        <template slot="text">
          <div>text text</div>
        </template>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row fullwidth gap">
      <inputText
        style="width: 100px;"
      />
      <inputText
        class="grow"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="row fullwidth gap">
      <label style="width: 100px;">
        <template slot="default">
          <div>Please type in the name of your city</div>
        </template>
      </label>
      <label class="grow">
        <template slot="default">
          <div>Please type in the name of your city</div>
        </template>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Other classes:

```
.row {
align-items: center;
flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
align-items: stretch;
flex-direction: column;
}

.fullwidth {
width: 100%;
align-items: start;
} 

.gap {
  row-gap: 12px;
  column-gap: 12px;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**Edit: Solved it by applying flex-wrap: wrap and white-space: normal on the label.**

Comment: Can you show the code you have currently?

Comment: without seeing the styles for all the classes(row, col, fullwidth...) you have used, it's hard to suggest a solution

Comment: Use a runnable snippet (https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make the code easier to read and visualise.